# 150 A 12 - 16 V DC Short Circuit Protection

Tags: automotive, protection, fuses

I am powering a ROV from a 4S LiPo battery (12.0 V minimum, 16.8 V maximum). The resistance of the battery is 36 mΩ, so that a maximum current of 470 A can flow through a short-circuit. In order to avoid risk of fire, I would like to implement short-circuit protection. The machine draws a peak current of 100 A (with a safety factor of 1.2 applied). Therefore the short-circuit protection device must trip at a current between 100 A and 470 A. I have been unable to find fuses that are rated at 12 V and a suitable Amperage. I have found the following product, intended for caravans and boats:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Carviya-Waterproof-Manual-Circuit-Breaker/dp/B074RDSDB9?ref_=fsclp_pl_dp_5&th=1

But I am unable to find a data sheet that confirms its specifications and timing. Could anyone please advise me whether a fuse or alternative circuit breaker for this application exists, and if so, if it would be sufficient to avoid damage to the vehicle?

Comment: *I have been unable to find fuses that are rated at 12 V and a suitable Amperage* Hmm, yet when I Google for "100A fuse" I get pleny of hits. Personally I would prefer a fuse as I consider a fuse to be more reliable (to break) than a circuit breaker in the event of an overcurrent. Circuit breakers for mains voltage have (require) all kinds of safety markings on them, the breaker you link to has none and that worries me.

Comment: You're not looking hard enough.  A fuse with a rating above 16.8V will be fine.  A quick Google quickly found a 32V 100A fuse from Littelfuse.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I couldn't (and still can't) find a fuse that is rated for 100+ A and between 12 - 16.8 V, could you please link me to a product that you think meets that specification? I think I have misunderstood the importance of voltage rating here.

Comment: @SimonB Could you please clarify what the purpose of the voltage rating of a fuse is? I think I haven't understood something basic.

Comment: Farnell: https://uk.farnell.com/c/circuit-protection/fuses-fuse-accessories/fuses?fuse-current=100a  (32 models) Ebay: https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_odkw=100A&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR2.TRC0.A0.H0.X100A+fuse.TRS0&_nkw=100A+fuse&_sacat=0 more than 4000 hits. Are you specifically looking for 12 -16.8 V fuses? There is no need for that. **Any voltage larger than 16.8 V will be OK**. I challenge you to find a fuse that **cannot handle 16.8 V**. 16.8 V is so low, almost **any** fuse can handle that and at 100 A all of them will.

Comment: the volts of a fuse rating relate more to arcing over the glass that power handling. to wit: wires (including fuse filaments) really don't care about voltage, they care about current. When looking at wire specs, the current relates to the metal, and the voltage relates to the pvc/silicone insulator, but they are not inter-twined under normal operating conditions, except at the most pedantic or ultra-precise scenarios.

Comment: @jholzer The voltage rating of a fuse is the maximum voltage that it is guaranteed to break.  There is never a problem using a fuse with a higher voltage rating.  However, with a DC load, you need to check the voltage rating on DC.